# Porque no muestra los números completos en excel con php-excel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Buenas Tardes quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy realizando una exportación de excel por la cual si exporta pero tiene un formato que por default le otorga  quisiera convertirlo en texto y se puedan ver los numeros en los campos

el dato que quisiera que se muestre es asi: 1312001712476

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo que utilizo es :

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("ListaObservacion");

    $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
    $objDrawing->setName('Logotipo');
    $objDrawing->setDescription('Logotipo');
    $objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
    $objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_PNG);
    $objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
    $objDrawing->setHeight(100);
    $objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
    $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

    $estiloTituloReporte = array(
        'font' => array(
            'name'      => 'Arial',
            'bold'      => true,
            'italic'    => false,
            'strike'    => false,
            'size' =>15
            ),
        'fill' => array(
            'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID
            ),
        'borders' => array(
            'allborders' => array(
                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE
                )
            ),
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
            'vertical' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER
            )
        );

    $estiloTituloColumnas = array(
        'font' => array(
            'name'  => 'Arial',
            'bold'  => true,
            'size' =>10,
            'color' => array(
                'rgb' => 'FFFFFF'
                )
            ),
        'fill' => array(
            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb' => '538DD5')
            ),
        'borders' => array(
            'allborders' => array(
                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
                )
            ),
        'alignment' =>  array(
            'horizontal'=> PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
            'vertical'  => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER
            )
        );

    $estiloInformacion = new PHPExcel_Style();
    $estiloInformacion->applyFromArray( array(
        'font' => array(
            'name'  => 'Arial',
            'color' => array(
                'rgb' => '000000'
                )
            ),
        'fill' => array(
            'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID
            ),
        'borders' => array(
            'allborders' => array(
                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
                )
            ),
        'alignment' =>  array(
            'horizontal'=> PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
            'vertical'  => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER
            )
        ));

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(50);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B6', 'N° CRÉDITOS');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$fila, utf8_encode($rows['NumeroCredito']));
```

lo que realice pero no me salio en colocarte este utf8_encode pero tambien  no me funciono

```
objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(50);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B6', 'N° CRÉDITOS');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$fila, utf8_encode($rows['NumeroCredito']))
```

Comment: Te aparecena así porque el campo que envias es muy grande trata de hacer mas grande la celda

Comment: @RaulCacacho el campo que deseo que se muestre solo tiene esto:
1312001712476

Comment: que tipo de dato es??

Comment: @RaulCacacho  en mi tabla es varchar(250) sql server y esos valores que estan ahi de ahi se exportan 

por eso realizo esto:

objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(50);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B6', 'N° CRÉDITOS');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$fila, utf8_encode($rows['NumeroCredito']))

Comment: aqui puedes hacer mas grande la celda ->setWidth(150) prueba así

Comment: @RaulCacacho igual lo que se agrando fue la celda pero el valor no se mostro igual

Comment: tenes que cambiarle el formato a la celda para que sea texto o darle un formato de número especifico

Comment: @aloMalbarez como podria cambiarle al formato texto

Comment: chusmeo el help y te cuento, asi de memoria no recuerdo =P

Comment: @Pierro prueba poniendole este formato de texto $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('B6')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(
        PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT
    );

Comment: @RaulCacacho en que parte de todo el codigo lo coloco segun la sintaxis que coloque mi hermano

Comment: @Pierro debajo de ->setCellValue

Comment: @RaulCacacho lo coloque en los dos lugares pero nada

Comment: `FORMAT_NUMBER` también puede funcionar, pero depende de la versión de excel =/

Comment: agregando un espacio delante lo sigue interpretando como numero grande? `setCellValue('B'.$fila, utf8_encode(" ".$rows['NumeroCredito']))`

Comment: @aloMalbarez eres genial si resulto hermano pon tu respuesta para darle check

Comment: muchas gracias me fue de gran ayuda para mostrar los dígitos usando el espacio en blanco " ".$variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según los estilos definidos

http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/ouardisoft/PHPExcel/class-PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat.html

Podes indicarle a la celda que sea de tipo general o sólo texto

```
$objPHPExcel
  ->getActiveSheet()
  ->getStyle('B'.$fila)
  ->getNumberFormat()
  ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

En algunas versiones de excel si agregas los números con un espacio a la izquierda te lo toma como texto, y no trata de mostrarlo en formato de "notación científica" o "exponencial". algo asi:

```
$objPHPExcel
  ->getActiveSheet()
  ->setCellValue('B'.$fila, utf8_encode(" ".$rows['NumeroCredito']))
```

Comment: lo coloque asi:

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B')
  ->getNumberFormat()
  ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT)->setCellValue('B'.$fila, utf8_decode($rows['NumeroCredito'])); 


me salio un error  Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::setCellValue()

Comment: hay que separarlo en dos lineas, en una set format y en la otra set value

Comment: como es eso hermano

Comment: resultó lo del espacio? lo otro puede ser la versión de la libreria

Comment: si resulto el espacio hermano :O 
pero como  seria segun la libreria

Comment: que versión de phpexcel es? según recuerdo hubo algunos cambios entre 1.7 y 1.8, lo del espacio por lo general funciona bien

Comment: la verdad no se que version de excelphp sera yo lo descarge nomas no domino bien el php

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76676/discussion-between-alo-malbarez-and-pierro).