# ¿Como puedo exportar un archivo en Excel que muestre los ceros a la izquierda usando librería PHPexcel?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Buen día, tengo unos datos en MySql los cuales exporto a Excel utilizando la librería PHPExcel, pero algunos de los códigos contienen "cero" a la izquierda, ejemplo: 010, pero al momento de generar el Excel el dato me queda como "10" y necesito que quede como originalmente es, o sea "010" ya he formateado las celdas utilizando esta sentencia:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

Aunque efectivamente me deja el archivo con todas las celdas en formato texto, me sigue quitando el cero de la izquierda, ya he intentado algunos códigos encontrados en algunos foros sin obtener el resultado que necesito, agradezco cualquier ayuda.
También he probado esto:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setSharedStyle($estiloInformacion, "A4:J".($i-1),PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: prueba agregarle un espacio delante como en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/159914/81450

Comment: Buenas tardes, probaste con `setCellValueExplicit()`?, es decir algo como: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('A1', '000000123');`

Comment: alo Malbares, gracias por la sugerencia, lo hice de esta manera:

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setSharedStyle($estiloInformacion,"". "A4:J".($i-1));


Pero sigue sin salir el cero de la izquierda.

Comment: Xerif, no entiendo tu sugerencia, lo que pasa es que el dato me lo llama desde la base de datos, esos códigos ya están predefinidos y son varios, no sé si lo que sugieres sirve porque ya me dice que cargue un número específico.

Comment: asegurate que hay un espacio entre las comillas así lo toma como texto, excel trata de ser "inteligente" (cree que es un número natural, le borra los ceros) y en casos como estos la pifia.

Answer (score 0):

Hola trata de ingresar un valor a la fuerza, sin la variable: $estiloInformacion , solo para revisar que no sea problema del PHPExcel_Cell_DataType , quizás el valor viene de la bases e datos sin el 0 o al momento de pasarla en php como variable..