# php headers excel number format

Tags: php, excel

necesito ayuda para imprimir números con un decimal cuando se trata de miles al generar un excel con php.  Lo que está pasando es quiero mostrar sólo un decimal al imprimir la hoja, pero sucede que al tener números de miles, por ejemplo, 1.298,8 me muestra con dos decimales así 1.298,80. Sólo pasa con los miles.  Los datos en la base de datos están bien.  Los headers que tengo son los siguientes:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Santiago');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=ficheroExcel.xls');
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
```

Comment: excel en varias de sus versiones intenta adivinar el formato de la celda cuando ésta es de tipo "general", podés forzar el tipo de celda a texto incluyendo un espacio delante del número ya formateado. si estás usando phpexcel para generar el archivo fijate si te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/159914/81450

Comment: engañar el excel con el espacio funcionó, pero le agrego un decimal igual a cero cuando el número es entero, alguna solución para eso?

Comment: una solución es un condicional cambiando el formato según sea entero o no. pero eso ya es medio forzar la visualización y tendrás que ver cómo se ve en un excel en español en un windows inglés, o si quien lo abre o recibe lo necesita pasar a otro locale (cambiar comas por puntos, etc)

Comment: creo que intentaré el condicional, ya que el reporte es de uso muy restringido.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que definirlo en los estilos de la celda.

Para cada celda, o rango de celdas, puedes decir el tipo de dato y/o formato.

```
/* Ejemplo de formato numérico, sin decimales */
$objPHPExcel
   ->getActiveSheet()
   ->getStyle("A1")
   ->getNumberFormat()
   ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER); 

/* Ejemplo de formato numérico personalizado */
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->applyFromArray(
    "numberFormat" => array(
       "code" =>  "#,###.#"  /* formato personalizado*/
    )
)
```

En la clase NumberFormat de PHPExcel tienes varios formatos predefinidos, ademas de poder darle tú el formato personalizado que quieras.

Comment: podrías agregar el formato para sin decimales con un condicional? así ya queda como respuesta

Comment: No entendí muy bien que es lo que quieres, ¿puedes explicarlo?